# DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 1 and head in Entity, line: 1

Tags: html, laravel

I am trying to convert laravel blade file to doc but it's show an error DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 1 and head in Entity, line: 1.

**Controller**

```
$admin = \App\Admin::all();

        $content = view('usersadmin.pdf', ['admin' => $admin])->render();

        $dom = new \DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($content);
        $dom->saveHTML();

        $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
        \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($phpWord->addSection(), $dom->saveHTML(), true);
        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        //$objWriter->save('doc_index_'.Carbon::now()->format('d-m-y h-i').'.docx');
        $objWriter->save('list-admin.docx', 'Word2007', true);
```

**blade file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>List Admin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>
<body>
  <style type="text/css">
    table tr td,
    table tr th{
      font-size: 9pt;
    }
  </style>
  <center>
    <h4>List Admin</h4>
  </center>

  <table class='table table-bordered'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Nama</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Alamat</th>
        <th>Telepon</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @php $i=1 @endphp
      @foreach($admin as $p)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
        <td>{{$p->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$p->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$p->address}}</td>
        <td>{{$p->phone}}</td>
        <td>{{$p->status}}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

I am wondering, is it not possible with this way?

Answer (score 0):

You are providing HTML format to your `DOMDocument` while it is expecting XML.
Rewrite your code in proper XML and the conversion will work.